# Multiplication with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working in a website where i am integrating order and payment gateway. I have three textbox. Textbox1, where i have the number of quantity and Textbox2, where i have cost of one order and in Textbox3 i am displaying the Total cost of Order. Now What i have to do is to get the Total order cost, depending upon number of order without page load with jquery or Ajax.

I have tried as follows, But it wont work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".Textbox1").keyup(function(){

    var valone = $('#Textbox1').val();
    var valtwo = $('#Textbox2').val();
    var total = ((valone * 1) * (valtwo * 1));
    $('#Textbox3 ').text(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not (directly) related to your question, but don't forget to add some error checking in case the user types non-numeric info (or negative numbers). Also I'd recommend that you get in the habit of using meaningful element ids and variables. If somebody else has to work on your code (noting that "somebody else" might be _you_ in six months' time) they won't know what "Textbox1", "Textbox2" and "Textbox3" are for and will have to go looking. Why not something like "quantity", "unitCost" and "totalCost"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
$('#Textbox3 ').val(total);
```

.val(value) Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.
You can read more on this [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but is

```
$(".Textbox1").keyup
```

meant to be

```
$("#Textbox1").keyup
```

Is it not working at all, or are you having problems with the wrong total being calculated?